# ID/Class Selector

Tags: jquery

I have some kind of problem with jQuery selectors.

Let's say i want to select `$('#elementID')` but the `elementID` is a variable.

There is any other possiblity to do this other way than `var variable = elementID; $('#'+variable)` ? I mean without specifying the `#` anywhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. You need "#" as a selector to select an ID. No reason to not use the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Or you could write your own function, something like:

```
$.id = function(id)
{
    return $("#" + id);
}

var elementID = "elementID";
$.id(elementID).text();
```

That would return an element with the ID of "elementID" without having to use the "#". Kind of pointless though.

Comment: Pointless, true, but it would have been nice if a simple function to get a single element by id would be in the core jQuery library. +1

Answer (score 3):

The following is probably the fastest and the cleanest solution:

```
$(document.getElementById(elementID))
```

Appending your variable to "#" would work of course, but it's inherently slower.

Comment: +1 for using standard DOM methods where appropriate. With `getElementById` you don't have to worry about the ID maybe having `.` (or `:`) characters in that would break the selector string if unescaped.

Comment: the problem is i want to REMOVE things from the source, not to add :) Besides that, i think jQuery uses standard selectors where is available.

Comment: I don't see where this makes a difference. If it does, I probably read your question wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but:

```
var variable = '#' + elementID;

$(variable)...
```

Answer (score 1):

If elementID  is a variable ala `var elementID = '#someId'`, I would suggest simply (although I didn't try it ):

```
$(elementID)
```

jQuery/JavaScript should dereference this variable as a string value and wrap the ID correctly for further operations...

Answer (score 1):

I use $('#'+variable) all the time.

Comment: I also use this format. But it seems is not too... elegant :)